# Character array elements get replaced when using printf

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I am taking the lines from a text file and storing the lines in an array. Then I am splitting the lines into separate words and storing them in another array. But I have a problem with the words stored.

Text file content:

```
 ls -l hahaha
```

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    char *trim (char *s) {
      int i = strlen(s)-1;
      if ((i > 0) && (s[i] == '\n'))
        s[i] = '\0';
      return s;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
        FILE *fp;
        char *output = NULL;
        fp= fopen("ints.txt", "r");
        //fscanf and fprintf is used for files and is same is printf and scanf
        fprintf(fp, "Testing...\n");
        //fgetsc for single character in file and fputc to write
        //
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        const char s[2]=" ";
        char *token;
        char line[256];
        char *lines[10];
        char *eof;
        char *args[10];
        
        //=====nulling the array lines====
        for(int p=0; p<10; p++)
        {
            lines[p]=NULL;
        }
    
        int i=0;
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            while(fgets(line, 256, fp)!= NULL)
            {
                lines[i] = strdup(line);
                //printf("%s", lines[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    
        int k=0;
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            if(lines[j]!=NULL)
            {
                token =strtok(lines[j], s); //s is the delimiter
                while(token != NULL)
                {
                    trim(token);
                    //printf("%s\n", token);
                    args[k] = token;
                    token = strtok(NULL,s);
                    k++;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n",args[0]);
        printf("%s\n", args[1]);
        printf("%s\n", args[2]);
        printf("%s something\n", args[0]);
        printf("%s something\n" , args[2]);  
        printf("program done\n");
    
    }
```

Output:

```
ls  
-l  
hahaha  
ls something    
 something     //the hahaha part disappears for the last printf**  
program done
```

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Why are you writing to a file opened for reading?

Comment: You mean you're not the least bit curious why you have *six* printf output lines, but only *five* actual printf invokes? The code posted should not (and frankly could not) have printed `-l something`.

Comment: Did you notice you have a missing newline on your last printf...???

Comment: @WhozCraig it was a typo. sorry. my actual problem is the last print f. when i print the element of that array + some character, then it just dissapears... dont understand why

Comment: Then correct the typo in you code posting... your posting must match the problem you are having... otherwise you are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @TonyB Done already sir.. thanks

Comment: I just did a refresh, and the last printf shows this:   printf("%s something" , args[2]); .... which is missing a newline...

Comment: @TonyB even if i add '\n' HAHAHA still doesnt show in the output.

Comment: On my linux system, without the newline , in the last printf, the last line of output is merged with the prompt... i.e. NOT on a separate line.

Comment: Try these things: 1) Add `\n` to the line `printf("%s something" , args[2]);` and 2) add `printf("Program done\n"); as the last line in your program and 3) test it and 4) update your question with the new code and output.

Comment: @4386427 i did update. thanks

Comment: I can't spot the problem and can't reproduce. The only thing I can think of is that `arg2[2]` is pointing to wrong memory. To debug I would start printing pointer values. Example: Change `//printf("%s", lines[i]);` into `printf("i=%d p=%p %s", i, (void*)lines[i], lines[i]);` and `printf("%s\n", args[2]);` into `printf("p=%p %s\n", (void*)args[2], args[2]); and `printf("%s something\n" , args[2]);` into `printf("p=%p %s something\n" , (void*)args[2] , args[2]);` and let us know the result

Comment: And maybe also `//printf("%s\n", token);` into `printf("token=%p %s\n", (void*)token, token);`

Comment: It may help if you could tell us what platform are you developing the program on, and what is the command that you are using to compile it...   For example, on my Linux system, I get an error on this line, "for(int p=0; p<10; p++)" that says it has to be compiled in C99 mode.... so knowing how you are compiling your program may help.